# How do you change the player color?

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive

How can I change the color on my name/picture in lobby and games?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change the actual colors in the settings. You can turn them [off](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/1xjm8j/teammate_color_option_fix_in_case_someone_missed/cfc3nty) or select a preferred color in the lobby, but without going into the files and changing it manually (which i don't recommend) it isn't possible.

[The patch notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20170525231645/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3226020) when the teammate colors were introduced. There is no mention of an option to change it in this or future patch notes.

Comment: Regarding your answer: Do you think you'd be able to provide an official source? We tend to reward answers that have a good bit of research behind them rather than speculation.

Comment: `cl_color` is the command (`0` for yellow, `1` = purple, `2` = green, `3` = blue, `4` = orange) — see [the answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/284004/148510)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `autoexec.cfg`... create the file if it does not exist in `/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/cfg/`

```
cl_color 0 // for yellow, cl_color 1 = purple, cl_color 2 = green, cl_color 3 = blue, cl_color 4 = orange

host_writeconfig  // if that doesn't set it, run exec autoexec in the console
```

Comment: `exec autoexec` is the command which reloads `autoexec.cfg` from the game and *by definition* doesn't require restarting...

Answer (score -1):

You can create a lobby, right click on your picture* and change color. It'll stay in that color in that lobby & the games you enter with that lobby. If you aren't 5/10 (5 for Competitive, 10 for Casual) in a lobby and somebody else selected same color too (in another lobby), your or his/her color will be random.

*By your picture, I mean this:
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Enter this in console and restart Counter Strike: GO:

```
cl_color 10 0 0
```

You will be bot colours.